# Javascript combine two string always take off the string after space?

Tags: javascript, string

I simply just try to combine two string like:

```
var temp = "<meta property='og:title'  content="; temp += "work1 work2"; temp += "/>";

document.write(temp);
```

But the result is always:

```
<meta property='og:title'  content=work1 />
```

But is should be:

```
<meta property='og:title'  content=work1 work2 />
```

I am new to javascript and any help is appreciated, thanks:-)

Comment: sorry, after i saw the highlighted "work2" I know what i did wrong, it should be temp += "'haha laiba'";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add single quotes for scope content attribut value:

```
var temp = "<meta property='og:title'  content='"; temp += "work1 work2"; temp += "' />";

document.write(temp);
```